# Which document format is this? (.MAN/.STR/.TAB/.IND)

Tags: ms-dos, file-format, text

I have these files, which were all in one `.zip`:

```
DPMANUAL.MAN
DPMANUAL.STR
DPMANUAL.IND
DPMANUAL.I01
DPMANUAL.I02
DPMANUAL.TAB
DPMANUAL.TXX
```

They are supposedly a manual (for DataPerfect).

The `file` command says that the `.STR` is "Corel PlanPerfect macro, v1.3" and the others are "data."

Opening the files in LibreOffice does not work. When selecting "Word Perfect" (which I thought it would be) they are not recognised.

What format is it? How do I convert them to something useful, preferably PDF ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least some of those files are DataPerfect files: `.STR` files are structure files, `.IND` files are index files, and `.TXX` files store data stored in variable-length text fields (see [*Mastering DataPerfect*](https://web.archive.org/web/20061014032117/http://dataperfect.nl/files/masteringdataperfect.pdf) for details).

The DataPerfect manuals are available as WordPerfect files and PDF files from [the DataPerfect Users Discussion Group](https://web.archive.org/web/20120314042340/http://dataperfect.nl/CMS/index.php?option=com_weblinks&Itemid=4&catid=12), as is [DataPerfect itself](https://web.archive.org/web/20120305102049/dataperfect.nl/CMS/index.php) (it was released as freeware in 1995 and maintained by its original developer until 2008).

Answer (score 6):

It would make sense that a manual for DataPerfect would be stored as a DataPerfect database - after all, handling arbitrary data was its main goal.

`.TXX`, `.IND`, `.Ixx` and `.STR` are known as DataPerfect file extensions.

Maybe have a look at [these pages](https://www.sanbachs.net/compusofl/), especially the [download area](https://www.sanbachs.net/compusofl/download.html) which offers an [archive with DPEXPIMP](ftp://www.sanbachs.com/dp/dpexpimp.zip), a tool to extract information from a DataPerfect database.

Comment: Did you manage to actually download anything from that site? The FTP server seems to be broken (logging in complains about not being able to change directory to `/var/ftp/`).

Comment: Nop, just searched for some place offering DPEXPIMP, as I remembered that tool.

Comment: `DPEXP.COM` and `DPIMP.COM` are available in the main DataPerfect archive.

Comment: That opens up a perfect chicken-and-egg problem, especially for the installation manual ;) Very clever idea ;)